# Android. Иногда PendingIntent = null и наступает FATAL EXCEPTION, как проверить?

Tags: android, service, pendingintent

Был такой код в IntentServices

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    try {

            pi.send(MyActivityTwo.STATUS_STOP);


  //} catch (InterruptedException e) {
      //e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (PendingIntent.CanceledException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "In onDestroy");
}
```

в pi иногда приходил null и приложение ломалось в строке `pi.send(MyActivityTwo.STATUS_START);`, тогда я решил делать проверку, но теперь оно ломается в строке `if (!pi.equals(null)){`

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    try {
        if (!pi.equals(null)){
            pi.send(MyActivityTwo.STATUS_STOP);
        }

    //} catch (InterruptedException e) {
        //e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (PendingIntent.CanceledException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "In onDestroy");
}
```

как это исправить, мне нужно чтоб когда pi был равен нулю, то ничего не происходило?

Comment: скорей всего MyActivityTwo возвращает null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думается мне, что на `null` нужно сравнивать оператором `==` `(!=)`, а не методом `equals()`.

Если `pi = null`, то для него не может быть вызван метод `equals()`, так как отсутствует объект для вызова метода и вы получите исключение *NullPointerExteption*

Соответственно:

```
try {
        if (pi != null){
            pi.send(MyActivityTwo.STATUS_STOP);
        }

    } catch (PendingIntent.CanceledException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```